# location of DTD file cannot be found

Tags: validation, jdeveloper, dtd

Using JDeveloper 12c, I am trying to validate the EMPLOYEES.XML file using a EMPLOYEES.DTD schema but I stil receive the warning message that says "Location was not found(employees.dtd)"

For more details, please have a look on below screenshot. In same screen I added the XML file and DTD file.

[image]

Can someone explain why this message appears?
I am expected to receive validation errors but not this warning.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your XML and DTD are in two different directories. (The XML is in `Resources` and the DTD is in `Application Sources`.)

You can either move them to the same directory or update the system identifier in the doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE employees SYSTEM "..\Application Sources\employees.dtd">
```

Comment: I would like to use different folders but with the solution you provided, I still have same error.

Comment: @mikcutu - Are the "Application Sources" and "Resources" directories pseudo directories? Looking at the file path in your screenshot is says "C:\JDeveloper\mywork\XMLFundamentalsWorkspace\XMLLabsProject\employees.xml" (there is no "Resources" directory). I'm unfamiliar with JDeveloper. Maybe try putting the full path to the DTD; whatever that might be.

Comment: I have tried to use the real directory but I have same error.